# Embed Responsive Youtube Video that fits into column width and height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube

When I embed the Youtube video it is much smaller than the column, I have tried setting the height and width differently but it doesn't seem to work. I must be missing something.. using bootstrap, HTML5 and CSS3

[this is an image to show what is happening and what I want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMCpl.png)

HTML.

```
<section id="one-head" class="one-head">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">



<div class="col-md-pull-1  col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 center">

<div class="videocab">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="100%" height="auto"    
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VzqVWbTIuuu?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="block wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow 
duration="500ms">
<h1>
text
</h1>

<h2>
text
text
</h2>

<p>
Ttext ijasfijvpeoa niA SPdfup ajfaksnf 'asFJh'aspfj     
uASIPFJAIPFHAS"JLFNhasf"J ASIF"ASIPF a asjpfaIFJapifjaSFJaPFJaspjfAPSJF   
POAJFpOAJSFpoajsfpAOSJFpoSAJFPoJASFPJASPOASJFPOASJFpojfOPAJFoasjfASOPJFsoap
fjOASJFoSAPJFAOJFAOPJFAOSPJFPOJFPAJFPOAJFspoajfOPASJF
<br>
<br>

<span><a class="anchor-textcab" href="#techspecs">Cabinet Colors</a></span>        
<span><a class="anchor-textcab" href="#techspecs">Cabinet Size</a></span>
<span><a class="anchor-textcab" href="#techspecs">Details</a></span>
</p>


<a class="btn-cab" href="contact.html">Request&nbsp;a&nbsp;Quote</a>  

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS.

```
#one-head {
padding-top: 5%;
padding-bottom: 4%;
}
#one-head .block {
padding: 20px 10px 30px;
}
#one-head .block h2 {
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: 500;
margin-bottom: 30px;
text-transform: none;
color: #00bfff;
}

#one-head .block h3 {
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: 400;
margin-bottom: 30px;
text-transform: none;
}

#one-head .block p {
color: #727272;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 28px;
margin-bottom: 35px;
}
#one-head .block img {
padding-top: 8%;
width: auto
}

#one-head .block .matrix-bold {
font-weight: 500;
margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to change the height from 100% to 400px.

```
<div class="videocab">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" 
        frameborder="0" 
        allowfullscreen="1"
        title="YouTube video player" 
        width="100%" 
        height="400px"   
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VzqVWbTIsuuu?color=white&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=light&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;playlist=3iboEi4GvQA&amp">
</iframe>

.videocab {
padding-top: 14%;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are styling your **.block** div, but not even touching the **.videocab** one.

First, you need to set the property `float` for both divs to set them in the left or right side of the screen.

Normally you would want the divs to have 50% `width` each, but you should consider the margin and padding that you already have, because it you have more than 100% it will look very odd.

Finally, set the desired `margin-top` and `padding-top` in the **.videocab** div like you do with your **.block** one just to avoid the video to appear at the top of the screen.

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fq8z5g9/) example based on your code, which should give you a clear idea of what I mean.

For older browser support and this basic usage, the properties I mentioned are able to solve your issue. However, I would also like to recommend you to use [**flexbox**](https://devdocs.io/css/css_flexible_box_layout) to lay out every element in your site in an easy and nice way.

Comment: your result is the same result that I have. I'm trying to make the video size larger. I included an image to show what I have and want I'm trying to accomplish. In the image the first one is what I have which is your result as well. I'm trying to get the video to be a similar length and width as the tet section beside it

Comment: Well, since you didn't provide too many details, I just did something similar to the third picture you attached.